# Firewire audio puzzle: works in Xenial but

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, firewire

It doesn't seem to be a variant of other questions on firewire.

Basicaly, my FW Solo works in Ubuntu 16 with pulseaudio (playback only but it's ok for my needs).
But... it has to be initialized by windows (10). If I boot into Win 10, and reboot into Xenial, I have pulseaudio playback. Otherwise, if I boot directly into Ubuntu, pulse shows volume control, everything seems fine but no sound output.
It's a bit frustrating because I guess there's just a simple things to do to "initalize the fw module". Alsa displays the card but amixer shows no controls.
carte 0: Solo [FW Solo], périphérique 0: BeBoB [FW Solo PCM]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0

I tried some asoundrc configurations without success.

In the morning, I boot into Win 10 and then reboot into Ubuntu 16 and all is well.

Comment: The driver author owns a FW Solo. Try asking on the [alsa-devel mailing list](http://www.alsa-project.org/mailman/listinfo/alsa-devel).